# QA Testing Flutter Application apk

Tags: flutter, testing, automated-tests, appium, katalon-studio

I would like to create automated tests for an application developed using Flutter.
The source code is not available. I only have access to the apk file.
Can you please guide me on how this may be done?

Iam using android studio to emulate an android 13 device.
I Tried using Katalon studio with Appium (Flutter Driver). I was able to run a simple test. The test ran once but failed afterwards and never ran again.